# How to autofill select tag in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a Rails app and am trying to get a select field to work properly.

I currently have in my _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_with(model: rec, local: true) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_field :description, id: :rec_description, :size => 100 %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :list_id %>
    <%= form.select 'list_id', options_for_select(@lists.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] })%>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

However, when I go to my edit view, the select field automatically defaults to the first choice in the field. I'd like it to remain what it was previously. Otherwise, the user will have to go back each time and change it.

I tried

```
<%= form.select 'list_id', options_for_select(@lists.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] }, :selected => form.list_id %>
```

Howevever, I get an error saying: undefined method `list_id'

How should I address this?

Comment: Add the entire `_form.html.erb`

Comment: @DanielWestendorf I included the entire _form.html.erb

Comment: "Howevever, I get an error saying: undefined method 'list_id'" - but of course, list_id is not a method on the form. It's a method on your record, `rec`. And it __should__ just work. Double check that `rec.list_id` is set to a valid id when rendering the form.